# setColor on transparent background not showing correct color

Tags: java, bufferedimage, graphics2d

I have a png image with transparency. I am trying to create a filled polygon on the image over the transparent area. I'm setting the color but the actual color in the final image is different than expected. Here is my code:

```
        Graphics2D g = wifiImage.createGraphics();
        int [] x = {0, 200, 0};
        int [] y = {0, 0, 200};
        g.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0)); //Red color
        g.drawPolygon(x, y, 3);
        g.fillPolygon(x, y, 3);
        g.dispose();
        ImageIO.write(wifiImage, "png", new File("./output/finalImage.png"));
```

In the final image, I expect the Red color triangle. But it is some brownish color instead.

As a workaround, in my origImage, I replaced transparency with white color. In that case, it works.

Can anybody tell how to set the correct color on the transparent region of the png?

Comment: Consider 1) posting the image, and 2) posting a more complete [mcve] (although your code is close), 3) posting what you're expecting, and 4) what you're getting

Comment: A color on another transparant color will never render like if it was alone, it 's a basis, https://www.modprint.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Bonus-colors.png

Answer (score 0):

The PNG image is probably a palletted image where 'brownish' is the palette color closest to (255, 0, 0).

Try this:

```
    BufferedImage copy = new BufferedImage(wifiImage.getWidth(), wifiImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); 
    g = copy.createGraphics();
    copy.drawImage(wifiImage, 0, 0, null);
    int [] x = {0, 200, 0};
    int [] y = {0, 0, 200};
    g.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0)); //Red color
    g.drawPolygon(x, y, 3);
    g.fillPolygon(x, y, 3);
    g.dispose();
    ImageIO.write(copy, "png", new File("./output/finalImage.png"));
```